# How to add tabIndex to MenuItem with material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tabindex

I am using `MenuItem` with Material UI to display a list for a user to choose the language.

For accessibility, I need the user to be able to tab through the list and choose one, but it is skipping this list and going to the next elemend in the DOM.

```
    <MenuItem
        tabIndex="0"
        className="menu-item"
        key={key}
        selected={i18n.language === key}
        onClick={() => {
            handleLanguageChange(key);
                }}
            >
            <ListItemText tabIndex="0" primary={languages[key]} />
            <ListItemIcon className="icon">
                <CheckCircleIcon className={'checkmark'} fontSize="small" />
            </ListItemIcon>
    </MenuItem>
```

The screenshot is from the dev tools and shows that the tab index is there, but it appears that it might need to be on a child element inside of the `<li>`.

Is there a different way of doing this that will allow for `tabIndex` to work?

[image: screenshot from dev tools]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the element above the list needed `tabindex="-1"` added to it.[image]

Comment: Is this the solution? If so - please mark it as the correct one.